# EasyMock - HibernateCallback.doInHibernate() method invocation

Tags: hibernate, easymock, powermock

How to create junit test method (using EasyMock & PowerMock) for below method from DAO class,

```
public List<MyVo> getSomeValue(final String systemId) {
    //assume template set by @Resource(name = "hibernateTemplate")
    HibernateCallback<List<MyVo>> callback = new HibernateCallback<List<MyVo>>() {
        @Override
        public List<MyVo> doInHibernate(Session session) {
            Criteria criteria = session
                    .createCriteria(
                            EntityClass.class,
                            "main");
            criteria.createAlias("AnotherName",
                    "ColName1");
            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("pkId",
                    systemId));
            return template.findByCriteria(MyVo.class, criteria);
        }

    };
    return template.execute(callback);
}
```

I googled it, but not able to get any solution. 
Please suggest. 
 Thanks.
VAm

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion in a unit test like this it is pointless to attempt to mock out the `HibernateTemplate`, as your test will then only assert that you call certain methods in a certain order - and with the exact fields that exist in the source code of your DAO class. This type of test doesn't add much value.

I think it's far better to test the DAO with a *real* `HibernateTemplate` hooked up to an in-memory SQL database, using something like DBUnit or just an external SQL script to set up the "pre" condition data you want in the database. Then you can assert that `getSomeValue()` returns the expected value given the data in the database.

This might be considered more of an "integration test" but IMO it's far more valuable then a useless unit test using a mock `HibernateTemplate` which only asserts that you call certain methods in a certain order.

Spring has good [JDBC testing support](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#integration-testing-support-jdbc) along with [the TestContext Framework](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-framework) which makes it dead simple to load a Spring context in your test and wire beans into your test class.

Answer (score 1):

One of the rules of mocking is: [Don't mock types you don't own](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=mock%20classes%20you%20dont%20own)

If you want to test a DAO, you'll get more value by writing an integration test rather than a unit test.